# PrettyPhoto plugin not working at all in my code

Tags: wordpress

I am using PrettyPhoto jquery plugin but its not working, here is the code I am using ...

```
<a href="'.$post_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($lop->ID)).'" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="'.$post_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($lop->ID)).'"></a>
```

It gives me my nice image even I have applied that `rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]`And in my js here is the code

```
//pretty photo js
$("area[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

$(".gallery:first a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',theme:'light_square',slideshow:3000, autoplay_slideshow: true});
$(".gallery:gt(0) a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'fast',slideshow:10000, hideflash: true});

$("#custom_content a[rel^='prettyPhoto']:first").prettyPhoto({
    custom_markup: '<div id="map_canvas" style="width:260px; height:265px"></div>',
    changepicturecallback: function(){ initialize(); }
});

$("#custom_content a[rel^='prettyPhoto']:last").prettyPhoto({
    custom_markup: '<div id="bsap_1259344" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6"></div><div id="bsap_1237859" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6" style="height:260px"></div><div id="bsap_1251710" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6"></div>',
    changepicturecallback: function(){ _bsap.exec(); }
});
```

All scripts and styles are added and there is no console error at all as well, kindly guide me quickly where is going wrong code ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every bit of code is fine and console is error free, then make sure you are using your targeted classes and IDs to make sure it gets proper path. Like shown below: 
In your case it will look like:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a href="'.$post_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($lop->ID)).'" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="'.$post_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($lop->ID)).'"></a>
</div>
```

and for your targeted ID, it will look like:

```
<div id="custom_content">
    <a href="'.$post_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($lop->ID)).'" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="'.$post_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($lop->ID)).'"></a>
</div>
```

and so your targeted content element will take pretty photo effects.

Comment: oooh, My target was not right, I was targeting in jQuery while there was no such element in mine HTML, thank you very much for pointing that out ...